# Nlog 5.2.8 log into elastic search in .net4.6

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nlog

I want to log in to Elastic Search with Nlog
my project is

```
WebApi .net 4.6 
NEST 6.2
Elasticsearch.Net 6.2
NLog 5.2.8
and Elastic Search 8
```

recently I decided to move to Elastic 8 from 5

In Elastic version 5, I didn't have any problem but I have to move to 8
I can't upgrade my dotnet version because some packages work only with .net 4.6
I tried to test upgrade my project to .net 4.6.1 and then update NLog and NEST,Elasticsearch.Net and worked correctly and I could log to elastic 8

but my problem is I can't change the version and unfortunately NLog dependencies packages are the latest version support for .net 4.6 and  if I want to update these I must upgrade my .net version

when my .net is 4.6 and when I want to log to elastic 8 with NLog config i get these logs

```
2023-12-31 00:08:08.4356 Error Failed to send log messages to elasticsearch: status=, message="Failed to ping the specified node.. Call: Status code unknown from: HEAD /"
2023-12-31 00:08:08.4356 Trace Failed to send log messages to elasticsearch: result=Unsuccessful low level call on POST: /_bulk
2023-12-31 00:08:08.4556 Error Error while sending log messages to elasticsearch: message="Failed to ping the specified node.. Call: Status code unknown from: HEAD /"
```

Comment: Check Migration Guide and Release Notes : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.11/breaking-changes.html

Comment: Following says Net 4.6.1 or higher (not 4.6) : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/introduction.html

Comment: thanks for the answer, in this link, describe how to upgrade the old elastic version to 8,  but I just want to write the log from .net 4.6 to elastic 8 by NLog.

Comment: I found release notes for 4.6.1 : https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/main/releases/net461/dotnet461-changes.md  Are you using HTTP or HTTPS. There were lots of Encryption errors that weren't fixed until 4.7.1.  You may be having a connection issue with establishing an encrypted connection with TLS.  Check you certificate and see what encryption mode is being used.  TLS 1.0 ands TLS 1.1 are obsolete and you need to used TLS 1.2 or 1.3.  Net 4.7.1 switches from using Net for TLS to OS.

Comment: I use HTTPS , and I added TLS connection , I don't get SSL error

Comment: TLS is performed before the HTTP request is sent.  If TLS fails the request is not sent.  Your error says "Failed to ping the specified node" which probably means the connection never completed and TLS failed.  TLS failure are timeouts.  I would try with HTTP and get that working.  I think the issue is the newer TLS 1.2/1.3 encryption  modes are not supported in Net 4.6.

Comment: I would recommend create a class in Core for the HTTPS connection.  See following on example of mixing Net and Core : https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/main/core/extensions/NetComSxS